# Is there a way to cache and display searched list via using autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to cache what has been typed into search area and then use it for another search. check out the below picture to see what I am trying to achieve.

Some of you may wonder why I did not use the **form autocomplete attribute**. The reason is that there is no removing the cached data. I want to bind it to a button to clear all cached data however the only way to do that as much as I know to disable the autocomplete attribute.  please correct me if I am wrong. therefore I decided to use localstorage.

[image]

here is the below fiddle to look at it. I am wondering if it is possible to use the source function of autocomplete as I have intended to use.

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
 </form>


jQuery('#myInput').autocomplete({
    source: localStorage.getItem(key)
  });
var list = [];
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

list.push(input.value);
localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(list));
input.value = "";

console.log(list);

for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

let key = localStorage.key(i);
console.log("localStorage.getItem", localStorage.getItem(key));


  jQuery('#myInput').autocomplete({
    source: localStorage.getItem(key)
     });
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cagatay07/6gqfozpr/92/

Comment: The logic here does not make sense. When I first come to the search, the `list` would have 0 items. So Autocomplete would not assist at this time. You need some type of source. Now, if you want to capture selected search items and make the the top hits first, that could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
$(function() {
  function getList() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.list) || [];
  }

  function saveList(arr) {
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(arr));
  }

  function updateList(item) {
    var l = getList();
    if (l.indexOf(item) < 0) {
      l.push(item);
    }
    saveList(l);
  }

  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateList($("#myInput").val());
    return true;
  });

  var list = getList();
  $("#myInput").autocomplete({
    source: list
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9dq2s80z/26/

Each time the form is submitted, it updates the Local Storage. This is then used in Autocomplete.

Comment: working smooth. I will bind it easily to a button to clear the cache.

Comment: I can not get the list visible when cursor is blinking in textbox. any configuration is needed for this?

Comment: @chatay see here: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search